# What is the relation between the length of period of simple continued fraction expansion of quadratic algebraic numbers $\sqrt{A}$ and the integer $A$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, computability-theory, transcendental-number-theory

What is the relation between the length of period of simple continued fraction expansion of quadratic algebraic numbers and the integer

As we know,$\sqrt{2} = [1;2,2,2,2,…]$; while $\sqrt{14}= [3;1,2,1,6,1,2,1,6…]$,let $L$ the length of period  of simple continued fraction expansion of quadratic algebraic numbers  be the number of integers  in sequence of one periods, that is  $L=i$ for   quadratic algebraic number$\sqrt{A}$,where $\sqrt{A} = [a_0;a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_i,a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_i,…]$.

We know different quadratic algebraic numbers may have different  lengths of period of simple continued fraction expansion  What is the relation between the length of period of simple continued fraction expansion of quadratic algebraic numbers and the corresponding integer $A$?It is looks like $L$ is relevent to the prime factors of $A$.Is there any formula?

Since we can decide there is a period or cycle,we possibly can compute the the length,otherwise we may get a set of increasing random sequences elements of which are   period of quadratic algebraic numbers and have another example of undecidable question.

Comment: Are you expecting there to be a simple rule? There isn't.

Comment: @KConrad，no,but if there is a simple rule,that is a surprise to me.But I don't think there is such a rule.Maybe there is a simple inequality .

Comment: See [here](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/596-continued-fractions/) for some references.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo,thank you,I am reading the blog and there are useful theorems

Comment: @AndresCaicedo,Yes,there is a simple inequality.And possibly,some theorems cited from literatures may be unified?